# How can I trim my pegboard?

Tags: tools, storage

I really want to tidy up my tool closet, and step one is getting the pegboard hung back up.

I'd like to mount the board on the inside of a closet door, but it is about 2" too wide for that. I've had it forever so don't know exactly what it is made of but it feels like some kind of MDF or hardboard. It's pretty sturdy.

I have a jigsaw, a circular saw, and a hacksaw. What's my best bet for cutting the pegboard without damaging it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the circular saw.

Clamp a piece of scrap 1" by something down to guide the saw for a straight cut. This will take some time to lay out, but it will be worth it.

Get your saw up to speed before cutting the hardboard.

Additional Tips from the comments:

Put masking/painters tape on the cut line and cut down the middle of the tape.  This will reduce splintering of the edges.

If using a circular saw, cut with the finished side down.  Splintering, if any will occur on the back side, which is hidden.

Pro-tip: A table saw with the blade lowered makes a perfectly serviceable dining room table.  It also makes carving a roast a breeze.

Comment: In addition, put painters tape on both sides of the pegboard where you intend to cut. Scribe your line on the tape, then cut.  The tape will help prevent fraying of the edges.

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo Just to understand you, I'd be cutting down the middle (roughly) of my tape?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  http://img.diynetwork.com/DIY/2011/02/24/RX-DK-DIY248019_carefully-saw_s4x3_lead.jpg -- that person's using a hand saw but the principle is the same.  The tape helps keep the cut edge neat and smooth.

Comment: Also, when using your circular saw, you will get the cleanest cut by putting the pegboard face down, and cutting along the back side.  The teeth cut upward on a circular saw, and the cleanest cut is on the bottom side while cutting (the good side of the pegboard as it's laying face down).  So any rough edge will be on the back of the pegboard.

Comment: If shaving only a few inches, would a table saw work better (it cuts a near-perfect line)?

Comment: @Annon: The circular saw you have always works better than the table saw you don't have (see list in Q). Might be a handy excuse to buy more tools though.

Comment: @AnnonomusPenguin, RedGrittyBrick Right ... if I had room for a table saw we wouldn't be organizing my tool closet. :)

Comment: @Amanda: I bet you only use your dining room one hour each day and a sawblade makes a lovely centrepiece! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a bench saw with a plywood blade for a nice clean cut; but any high tooth count blade will work because it is just compressed paper.